# Такое поведение вложенных контейнеров

Tags: css, css3

Помогите понять поведение. Ожидаю кружок по центру. Проблема решается, или увеличением контейнера а1, или а2 c display: block;

```css
.a1 {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
}
.a2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
  <span class="a2">
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По дефолту для текста и inline'овых элементов (в том числе `display: inline-block`) стоит значение `vertical-align: baseline`, что означает, что выравниваются такие элементы по "нижней границе текста не учитывая выносных элементов (свисающия пиксели у букв типа р, щ и так далее)", эта "базовая линия" высчитывается в зависимости от шрифта и его размера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае, так как у вас не заданы ни позиционирование по вертикали inline'овых элементов, ни высота строки, ни размер шрифта, они берутся "по дефолту". Соответственно высота строки у вас примерно в районе 14-18px в зависимости от шрифта, базовая линия таким образом примерно в районе 2-3px "вверх от низа строки". Итого у вас "доступная" высота из-за ограничения контейнера - 6px, а базовая линия находится на высоте примерно 14px от верха вашего контейнера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меняя тип на `display: block;` вы убираете эти правила, меняя размер блоков вы так же нивелируете разницу между высотой строки и высотой контентной области. А так как, если высота inline элементов выше высоты строки, то они упираются в верхнюю границу, то у вас получается "круг в центре".

То есть в вашем случае желаемый результат может так же быть достигнут и при `.a1 { font-size: 0; }` (так как высота строки будет задаваться в зависимости от высоты вложенного `inline-block` элемента, а базовая линия будет являться нижней границей высоты строки)
, а так же при `.a2 { vertical-align: top; }` (так как выравнивание уже будет не по базовой линии, а по верхней линии "текста").